# ng-repeat not bind ng-model array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm try to bind array of objects to html. But when I changed input value, model not changed. What i'm doing wrong?

Sorry, this is very simple case, but i'm confused.

My html:

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <table class="price-table">
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in prices track by $index">
                    <td><span>{{item.country_code}}</span></td>
                    <td><input ng-value="prices[$index].price" ng-input="item.price = item.price" ng-disabled="!item.editMode" type="text"/></td>
                    <td><button class="btn price-table-btn" ng-click="item.editMode = !item.editMode" ng-disabled="item.noEdit">&#9998;</button></td>
                    <td><button class="btn price-table-btn" ng-click="savePrice($index, item)" ng-disabled="!item.editMode">&#10003;</button></td>
                    <td><button class="btn price-table-btn" ng-click="removePrice($index, item)" ng-disabled="!item.editMode">&times;</button></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
     <div>
            {{prices}}
        </div>
        </div>
```

My code:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp')
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.prices = [{"country_code":"00","price":"12.00","editMode":false,"noEdit":false},{"country_code":"01","price":"1.00","editMode":false,"noEdit":false},{"country_code":"AU","price":"8.00","editMode":false,"noEdit":false},{"country_code":"CA","price":"5.00","editMode":false,"noEdit":false},{"country_code":"GB","price":"10.00","editMode":false,"noEdit":false},{"country_code":"UK","price":"10.00","editMode":false,"noEdit":false},{"country_code":"US","price":"3.00","editMode":false,"noEdit":false}];
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jaxxreal/ntb5b79w/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ng-model

```
<input ng-model="item.price" ng-disabled="!item.editMode" type="text"/>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/86em52vm/)

[ng-value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) is not used for 2 way binding, it is used for select/input-radio elements

Answer (score 0):

You need to use, `ng-model="prices[$index].price"`

instead of, `ng-value="prices[$index].price"`

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/madena/1/)